# How to create custom beamer template

Tags: beamer, templates

I want to create a custom beamer template, for the slides to look something like this

[image].

How can I go about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think the first thing you want to do is browse the themes available in the standard distribution.  For that, look in the beamer manual, Part III.  Then read about how beamer selects templates, fonts, and colors in Part II.  Then start looking at the source code for the theme files, which are located in `${TEXMF}/tex/latex/beamer/themes`.

This is not an easy thing to do, but if you find something that exists close to what you want you might be able to adapt it.

Comment: The quickest way to browse the standard themes is probably with the [beamer theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)

Comment: There's also the [Beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/).